# Filter events in Google Calendar by date

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

How can I filter the events by start date and end date.

Example: start 03/15/2013, ending 03/20/2013;

I want to show all dates of these events, including those that began before and ending during or after the end, and those who started between the dates but will end after the final date

Exemple:

```
This include:

    Start: 03/10/2013, ending 03/17/2013
    Start: 03/10/2013, ending 03/22/2013
    Start: 03/17/2013, ending 03/18/2013
    Start: 03/17/2013, ending 03/22/2013

And exclude:

    Start: 03/10/2013, ending 03/12/2013
    Start: 03/22/2013, ending 03/23/2013
```

I'm using Google Calendar API V3 for Java

In my code, I have:

```
List find = service.events().list(calendarID);
```

I can use `find.setTimeMin` and `find.setTimeMax`, but this is not enough